# Inability to connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm quite to new to SQL Server, and I'm having difficulties creating a data source to enable me perform such functions as create a cube or using the Report Server Project Wizard. It appears that I'm unable to connect to the SQL Server instance on my machine; having had a look at a similar question on this forum, it may seem that this might be due to the instance that I am trying to connect been set up as one with only Windows Only Authentication rather than Windows and SQL Server Authentication, and the need for me to have a domain account set up. However, I'm unable to locate where to make this change/create domain account. I have clicked on "Properties" after right clicking on server (from the windows start menu) but cannot locate the place on the "Security" menu to change from Windows Only Authentication to Windows and SQL Server Authentication.

Are you able to point me in the right direction please?

Thank you

OG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable SQL Server user logins as well as Windows Authentication you will need to connect to your SQL Server instance using the SQL Server Management Studio.

Once connected you can modify the type of enabled server authentication by following the article below:

[Enabling Mixed Mode Authentication in SQL Server](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2008/04/03/Enabling-Mixed-Mode-Authentication-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

---

**Edit**

You may also need to enable the sa user. To do this follow the steps in the article below:

[How to enable sa Account in SQL Server?](http://sudeeptaganguly.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/how-to-enable-sa-account-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Hi jdavies. Many thanks for the response. I'd give it a go, and see how it goes.